# tense choice: is or was a former classmate?

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-tense

Which tense should be used in the following?

> He is/was a former classmate of mine.

Comment: Both are valid, meaningful sentences; it depends on context, and what you're trying to say. So: what is the context, and what are you trying to say?

Comment: Downvoted because asker did not clarify the context after request.

Answer (score 5):

If you're speaking in a past tense you would say 'was', but if you are speaking in the present tense it's 'is'. Since you are currently describing him in the present as a former classmate, you would say "he is a former classmate." If you want to say what he *was*, you would say "he was a classmate."

Comment: Re: "you are currently describing him in the present as a former classmate": How can you tell?

Comment: @Barmar That is logically true, but irrelevant to the grammar. If you say "He is a former classmate, and ten years ago we founded a company together" the mixture of present and past tenses are confusing.  (The company was not founded *ten years ago* because *he is still a former classmate now*.) "He *was* a former classmate..." would be better. On the other hand "He *is* a former classmate, and we *are* now co-directors of a company we founded 10 years ago" would be fine.

Comment: "If you're speaking in a past tense, 'was'. If the present tense, 'is'." Looks like some sort of circular argument. He is asking precisely about which tense to use in this situation. You give no hint as to how to choose it. I really wonder how this has been upvoted six times.

Answer (score 5):

The rule in this case is simple.

If the person you are describing is alive, you should say: he is a former classmate of mine.

If the person you are describing is dead, you should say: he was a former classmate of mine.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. It's true that if the person is dead, then we say "was" (the implication being "[...] when he was alive"); but that's not the only situation where we say "was".

Comment: He was a former classmate, then we decided to start a company together

Comment: If the person is dead, certainly "was" would be the correct form. If alive, either form could be used, although "former" along with "was" is a bit redundant. Thus, either "he is a former classmate..." or "he was a classmate...", so long as from the context it's clear that he is still alive.

Comment: @ruakh I don't see how it is helpful to say "that's not the only situation where we say 'was'" without giving at least one of such situations as an example to prove your point.

Comment: @LoremIpsum: I'm surprised by your suggestion that it's not helpful to warn other readers that an answer is not entirely correct. But FWIW, here's one example: https://books.google.com/books?id=Pjm0WzjI9k0C&pg=PA699&dq=was-a-former.

Comment: @ruakh Just to clarify, I don't say that warning that an answer is incorrect is not helpful; however, it is perhaps only helpful if you back up your point. I don't think "this is incorrect, period" is helpful. Thanks for sharing one such reference that clearly backs up your point (I think it would be the best answer if you converted the comment to an answer by the way).

Comment: @LoremIpsum: When a mistaken answer includes no support whatsoever, I don't feel obligated to put in a lot of effort to support pointing out the mistake.

Comment: @ruakh I could flag your comment for a misleading and even a slightly biased comment. Why haven't you said the same for answers below without any reference? The answer is true in general. It is not a mistaken answer. I could not find any reference for the use of is-was with former classmate. The rule is true in most cases. As correctly pointed out by Barmer,  the exception is when the person became classmate again.

Comment: On a side note, it feels good to know my answer is shown by Google for the same question.

Comment: @SyedDanishAmar: I see that I've offended you. That was not my intention; I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

A former classmate is someone who was a classmate in the past, but they're no t a classmate now.

Normally you would use "is". If someone was a former classmate in the past, they're still a former classmate now.

An exception would be if you were classmates in the past, stopped being classmates (one of you graduated, changed schools, etc.), and then became classmates again, and you still are classmates. Then you need to use the past tense to refer to the time when you were not classmates.

> Last month he *was* a former classmate. Now we are classmates again.

Answer (score 0):

"Former classmate" is a status that someone either has or does not have at any given moment in time. As with other sentences, the tense is primarily driven by what you are trying to communicate. It may be a bit more confusing here because the term "former classmate" involves events that are in the past *relative to the time at which the status applies*.

If you are talking about the person's current status (present tense), you can say

> He is a former classmate.

meaning he was a classmate some time ago and is no longer a classmate. If you are talking about the person's status at a previous time (past tense), you can say

> He was a former classmate.

meaning he was a classmate some time *before the time you are talking about* and was no longer a classmate *at the time you are talking about*.

So, "former" has its own temporal meaning that *layers on top of* whatever tense you use.